# PHP showing someone's user profile by taking MYSQL infos in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
        include_once 'info.php';  
    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `ID`, `Info1`, `Info2`, `Info3`, `Info4`,`Info5`,`Info6`, `Info7` FROM `users` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 9999999999");  
    if($query -> execute())   
    {  
        $query_results = $query->fetchAll();

    }  foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
    }
<html>
<tbody>
<?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
                             ?>  
           <tr>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["ID"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["Info1"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["Info2"]; ?> <?php echo $query_result["Info3"];?> <?php echo $query_result["Info4"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["Info5"]; ?> </td>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["Info6"];  ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $query_result["Info7"];  ?></td>
              <td>                                  <a class="btn btn-success" href="profiles/<?php echo $query_result["ID"]; ?>">
                                        <i class="halflings-icon white zoom-in"></i>  
</td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?></html>
```

Hello. The code from above is my searchperson.php (not included database conf and so on, it just how I echo every user from "users" inside a table.)
And inside my table, I have an eye (iclass) which I can click on it and redirect me to www.domain.com/users/ID

My question is, how can I make only ONE page, static page, which will show ID's infos?

Exemple: I click on ID1,  a new page www.domain.com/user/1  will pop up. I don't have any folder named "1". And I don't want to create any folder for every user. I just want to show ID 1's informations on www.domain.com/user/1
And if I click on ID2,  to show ID 2's information on www.domain.com/user/2.   (Or, www.domain.com/user?2,  it doesn't matter.)

Comment: are you using a framework or a front controller pattern?

Comment: In your query, you have `Info7FROM` which should be `Info7 FROM`. I also don't see the point of the `LIMIT` if you're going to put that high of a number?

Comment: @delboy1978uk front controller pattern I think, it's a school project, I'm using PHP and HTML with help of MYSQL databases.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So I should remove LIMIT, thanks.

Comment: One option is to implement the front controller pattern, like @delboy1978uk wrote. That way, every request will be redirected to some controller that will fetch data from the chosen ID and give the return back to the view. As it is too big to answer, I suggest you google and find by yourself some tutorial.

Comment: Instead of passing the id as a URL segment, you could pass it in the query string: `/foo?id=1` and then get the value with: `$id = $_GET['id'] ?? 0` on the other page.

Comment: Magnus I think that's what he wants rid of

Comment: @delboy1978uk - I don't see any reference to that in the question though? Anyway, it was just an option. You've already posted an answer about how they can do it using rewrites. :-)

Comment: I don't really need a specific link. I want, when I click on a user's ID, (in table I have all users), to redirect me to an php page with my own template and to show that specific ID's informations, and if I click on another ID, to show new ID's,

Comment: Note that should ever actually find yourself in a situation where you have enumerated column names (e.g. `Info1`, `Info2`, `Info3`), then it might be time to consider whether your schema design is in fact optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of way to do this is to create page `user.php` and use [GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to send data.

Create link:

```
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $query_result["ID"]?>">your link</a>
```

On your user.php now you can access to GET variable.

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: If I make an mysqli_query with WHERE ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'"); would work?

Comment: @Emin Eryilmaz Yes of course.

Comment: however thats a sql injection security risk. sanitize your inputs!!!

Comment: @delboy1978uk You're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a framework or front controller pattern (single entrypoint for your app), then you can use an Apache rewrite, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user([^/]*)$ /user-info.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not really answerable with PHP, this is dependant more on what your server is using. You want URL rewriting - [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) is an introduction to the topic which should help you get what you need.

For example the URL you want of www.domain.com/user/1 will actually be rewritten to www.domain.com/profile.php?userid=1

If you don't care about presenting a friendly URL to the user such as www.domain.com/user/1 then you could simply create a profile.php PHP page which takes in an ID parameter via GET in the URL and presents the profile information accordingly.

Comment: It's completely doable in PHP if using a front controller pattern - you could use a routing library, or just roll your own

Comment: You still need URL rewriting for that to work, no? ie mod_rewrite in Apache. To my knowledge there is no way to do this with pure PHP.